# understand the resultset of the below query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
with sample_data as (
  select 1 id, 1 num, 'Hello' val from dual union all
  select 1 id, 2 num, 'Goodbye' val from dual union all
  select 2 id, 2 num, 'Hey' val from dual union all
  select 2 id, 4 num, 'What''s up?' val from dual union all
  select 3 id, 5 num, 'See you' val from dual)

select id,
NUM,

CASE
  WHEN ID=1 THEN
    SUM(NUM) OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN NUM=3 THEN ID END  )
END AS SUM_1,


from sample_data
```

Can any one help me to understand the how this query will work..case inside the partition make me difficult to understand the resultset for this query. I am l

Answer (score 0):

(Ignoring the comma before the `from` that generates a syntax error.)

There are two case statements.  The outer one is saying "I'm only going to assign a number when the `id` is `1`.  Everything else will get a `NULL` value.

The inner one is calculating the value.  It is splitting the data into two groups, those with `num = 3` and everything else.  The calculation is the `sum` of `num`.

So, the query is doing the following.  It is assigning the sum of num where either num is equal to 3 or not equal to 3 to each row where `id = 1`.